# Am I using flexbox incorrectly? - 2 column flexbox error

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having an issue with flexbox and applying a 2 column layout - I wish to have the first 2 `divs` in one column and the third `div` to fill the second column by itself.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.flex-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 1200px;
}

.item1,
.item2 {
  height: 600px;
}

.item3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-cont">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks,

Comment: working as expected https://jsfiddle.net/3wLg7n4q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check with the below code, hope it will work for you. We have removed "*flex-grow*" property from the 3rd div and give a height to it.

Please refer to this link https://jsfiddle.net/906eq37f/1/

```css
.flex-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 1200px;
}

.item1, .item2 {
  height: 600px; 
  background : #ccc;
}

.item3 {
  background : #f5678a;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-cont">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works even with flex-grow....